# Generating a scalogram of a signal

Tags: fft, signal-processing, wavelet

I'm trying to build a scalogram view for my app to see whether there is relevant information we can retrieve from a wavelet transform as opposed to using a spectograms to see what can be retrieved via an FFT.

So far I can take a wave form and I can perform the forward wavelet transform on it.  However I am lost at the next step.  How do I turn this information into power/energy information?  I have a set of wave forms at different frequencies but I have, as I say, no frequency information.

Can anyone tell me what the next step is for turning this transformed data into a scalogram?

Any help would be much appreciated because my google skills are failing me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under reasonable assumptions, the discrete wavelet transform (DWT) decomposes the power/energy/variance of a time series into scales.  It is an energy-preserving transform in that the total variance contained in the original time series is contained in the squared wavelet coefficients (properly normalized), just like the DFT!  I think the text [Wavelet Methods for Time Series Analysis](http://staff.washington.edu/dbp/wmtsa.html) by Percival and Walden is an excellent resource for this type of information.

Now, the continuous wavelet transform (CWT) is a redundant transform and the energy-preserving property (in the DWT) no longer holds.  However, you can still look at the squared wavelet coefficients to produce the "scalogram" which is similar to the short-time Fourier Transform (STFT; aka spectrogram).

Torrence and Compo have some nice [wavelet software](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/software.html) to do this, with a paper to explain the method(s) in the context of atmospheric time series.  I'm sure the matlab wavelet toolbox also performs the CWT and associated scalogram.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd already discovered the energy preservation thing.  So I have some wavelet data appearing by calculating the power for each frequency band.  Its not great but certainly shows me some info :)  I'm still lost as to how to do a CWT though ... have spent quite a lot of time looking into it.  I assume its a bit more than just doing a sliding window DWT?

Comment: Two (major) things differentiate the CWT from the DWT: (1) the wavelet and (2) the translations used to compute the wavelet coefficients.  The CWT uses a continuous function was it's wavelet generating function (Morlet, 1st derivative of Gaussian, etc.) and computes a wavelet coefficient at all translations at all scales.  Thus, the CWT for a 1D signal (time series) produces a 2D image of (heavily correlated) wavelet coefficients.  The DWT uses a discrete function as the wavelet GF and produces the same number of wavelet coefficients as original observations.  Use Torrence/Compo's software!

Answer (score 2):

I've never done a scalogram so I won't claim to try and know anything. I have however found you the code for the matlab scalogram function which is commented in a way that should help you understand things a bit better.... I hope :).

http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/FrequencyFilt/scalogram.m

I'm presuming you're using matlab for your dsp stuff and know how to interpret that m file. Probably a manditory program for all dsp stuff I guess.